# Change default routes Devise Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have this `routes.rb`:

```
  devise_for :users, :path => '', path_names: 
                          { sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout", sign_up: "registration"}
```

I changed `sign_in` and `sign_up` routes and if you go to `sign_up` you will get 404 error, instead `/registration` will work. What I want is to change and add other routes like forgotten password in the same way.
If I type in the console `rake routes`, I see this for forgotten password:

> new_user_password GET      /password/new(.:format)        devise/passwords#new

How can add the additional routes in a way that my custom defined route will work, but not the default?

Answer (score 9):

Be sure to checkout the ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper#devise_for documentation [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper%3Adevise_for).

You can just simply do something like this-

```
devise_for :users, path: 'auth', path_names: { sign_in: 'login', 
                                               sign_out: 'logout',
                                               password: 'secret',
                                               confirmation: 'verification',
                                               unlock: 'unblock', 
                                               registration: 'register',
                                               sign_up: 'cmon_let_me_in' }
```

Comment: Yes I tried this, `path_names: {password: '/forgotten-password'},`, but it generate URL like this http://localhost:3000/forgotten/new, I don't want this string `new`

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example for the sessions, registrations, and passwords controller actions/routes:

```
devise_for :users, skip: [:sessions, :registrations, :passwords]

devise_scope :user do
  # sessions
  get    'login',  to: 'devise/sessions#new',     as: :new_user_session
  post   'login',  to: 'devise/sessions#create',  as: :user_session
  delete 'logout', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :destroy_user_session
  # registrations
  put    '/account',  to: 'devise/registrations#update'
  delete '/account',  to: 'devise/registrations#destroy'
  post   '/account',  to: 'devise/registrations#create'
  get    '/register', to: 'devise/registrations#new',    as: :new_user_registration
  get    '/account',  to: 'devise/registrations#edit',   as: :edit_user_registration
  patch  '/account',  to: 'devise/registrations#update', as: :user_registration
  get    '/account/cancel', to: 'devise/registrations#cancel', as: :cancel_user_registration# passwords 
  # passwords
  get   'new-pass',  to: 'devise/passwords#new',    as: :new_user_password
  get   'edit-pass', to: 'devise/passwords#edit',   as: :edit_user_password
  patch 'edit-pass', to: 'devise/passwords#update', as: :user_password
  post  'new-pass',  to: 'devise/passwords#create', as: :user_password
end
```

As seen in the 4th code sample block in [this wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes)

Comment: I know how to do that for :sessions, :registrations. It is not same for :passwords and I don't know what is. That's why I am asking.

Comment: Its the same thing for passwords. Have you tried my example above for passwords? you have to skip the controller first then redeclare

Answer (score 1):

You need to skip `passwords` and rebuild its routes as you want,

```
devise_for :users, skip: [:passwords]
devise_scope :user do
  match '/forgotten-password' => 'devise/passwords#create', as: :user_password, via: [:post]
  match '/forgotten-password' => 'devise/passwords#update', via: [:put, :patch]
  get 'forgotten-password', to: 'devise/passwords#new', as: :new_user_password
```

end

Your custom routes will work. And it skip all routes in that modules.

> NOTE : You need to overwrite all remaining routes of that module as you want.

Comment: Hi, yes I did that. The problem is that, there are  PUT and PATCH requests for same URL and action and if I change it in the routes.rb - ` match '/forgotten-password' => 'users/passwords#update', as: :password, via: [:put, :patch]` and then use the default view from Devise. the URL generated for the form - `<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: password_path(resource_name),` is `/forgotten.user`, which is not the correct URL.

Comment: Oh you need to format all routes. as well as you need to take care of  key `:as`, as devise update routes based on resource.
`as: :possword` don't work.

Please checkout updated answer answer

Comment: After changing routes, please restart server. so devise can understand your new routes.